# Why don't my featureLayer labels display when using timeSlider widget (Javascript API for ArcGIS 4.14)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

You only see all the labels when the slider has gone through the full time extent; at initialization there is nothing, they then start rendering as the slider plays.

Anyone know what the issue is? See my codepen here: https://codepen.io/cvricella2/pen/eYNxdQg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a bug with the new API ([Reference](https://community.esri.com/message/918650-re-why-dont-my-featurelayer-labels-display-when-using-timeslider-widget-javascript-api-for-arcgis-414?commentID=918650&et=watches.email.thread#comment-918650)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your code, but isn't it because you set the 'where' clause on timeSlider change?

```
labelClass.where = whereClause
```